# Presence insights server results in an initialization error

Tags: deployment, server, instance, ibm-cloud, presenceinsights

The presence insight server on bluemix has been quite unstable now. Cannot get access to the server.

Is there any way to deploy the instance on softlayer server for production?

Comment: I got this error when launching the service.                                                          "There was an issue during some of the initialization."

Answer (score 1):

There were definitely some problems with PI last evening, but the team worked until early this morning to get them resolved.  It looks like the system is back up and functioning.  Are you still seeing the issue?

Also, as a general reference, [this page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) has service status details on it that may be of help if you notice a problem.